# bar plot the sum, not mean value of a column

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

I am the beginner with seaborn plot. as the sample, seaborn provides a bar graph with the average "days". However, is it possible to provide a bar graph with total(sum), counting, of the days values?

```
import seaborn as sns 
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
ax = sns.barplot(x = "day",y = "total_bill",data=tips)
```

Answer (score 24):

From the docstring:

> ```
> Parameters:
> -----------
> [...]
> estimator : callable that maps vector -> scalar, optional
>     Statistical function to estimate within each categorical bin.
> ```

So

```
ax = sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, estimator=sum)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The question was asked quite a long time ago but being a beginner I landed up here and could find a solution for count which kind of works

```
from numpy import count_nonzero
ax = sns.barplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips, estimator= count_nonzero)
```

possibly count_nonzero was introduced long after the question was asked

Comment: An answer should answer the question in the OP, not some other question. This does not answer the question because it produces an incorrect result given the sample data. Review [answer].